# Update buttons not working on plotly R charts

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to use the update buttons in plotly r charts where in the user can change the chart type to group or stacked. The group bar chart works for the first time but stacked never works. Below is the code I am using.

```
library(plotly)

Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)

chart_types <- list(
  type = "buttons",
  direction = "right",
  xanchor = 'center',
  yanchor = "top",
  pad = list('r'= 0, 't'= 10, 'b' = 10),
  x = 0.5,
  y = 1.27,
  buttons = list(
        list(method = "restyle",
         args = list("type", "stack"),
         label = "Stack"),
    list(method = "restyle",
         args = list("type", "group"),
         label = "Group")
  ))

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo')%>% layout(updatemenus = list(chart_types))
p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. The barmode (group/stack) is a layout option and not different chart types:

```
library(plotly)

Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)

chart_layouts <- list(
  type = "buttons",
  direction = "right",
  xanchor = 'center',
  yanchor = "top",
  pad = list('r'= 0, 't'= 10, 'b' = 10),
  x = 0.5,
  y = 1.27,
  buttons = list(
    list(method = "relayout",
         args = list("barmode", "stack"),
         label = "Stack"),
    list(method = "relayout",
         args = list("barmode", "group"),
         label = "Group")
  ))

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo') %>% layout(updatemenus = list(chart_layouts), barmode="group")
p
```

Accordingly you need to use `relayout` instead of `restyle`.

Please see the [documentation](https://plot.ly/r/custom-buttons/) for details.